# I need to open a local html for each item in listview, how do? Android

Tags: html, listview, webview, load, local

I have a listview with onclick, but I need each item clicked open a html in assets folder, I have some html .. then need to open each item one.

Comment: whats the issue then? just load them

Comment: I want to know is how, what line to use to call for each item to call a particular html. @Akhil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to open local html file from your app assets folder

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(this, WebviewActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("url","file:///android_asset/local.html");
 startActivity(intent);
```

**WebviewActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebviewActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView mWebView;
    private String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        url=intent.getStringExtra("url");
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

activity_webview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/webviewRootContainer"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: With that I will be able to open an html, need to start from position 0 to the item to fill the listview.
example:

if (position == 0) {
  / * Open 01.html in assets folder * /
}

if (position == 1) {
  / * Open 02.html in assets folder * /
}